# How to check if a certain object is the only object in a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if (myArray contains only myObject) {
    //Do stuff...
} else {
    //Do different stuff...
}
```

What should I do to make the `if (myArray contains only myObject)` line actually check if `myArray` contains only `myObject`?

The object will not be in the array more than once and will be in position 1 (not position 0) only. So, using myArray.length won't help (maybe?).

I'm using `.splice` to add an object into `myArray` at position 1 so position 0 should be undefined.

Comment: Can the object be in the array more than once?

Comment: 1 - check if the array has a length === 1, then; 2 - check if array[0] is "myObject"

Comment: @mjw I edited the question.

Comment: If the object is at position 1, what's at position 0? Some non-object?

Comment: check array length is 2, array[1] is "myObject" and array[0] is undefined ( or array does not have own property of "0")

Comment: Please show all relevant code as per [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

you want to check two conditions:

first, the length of the array can only be 2 (since we have the object at instance 1)

second, the first index must be undefined.
so

```
if(myArray.length ==2 && myArray[0] === undefined &&(myArray[1] == myObject)){
//some code
}else{
//some other code
}
```

edit: just a note, we can still take advantage of the array length since we know that the index we set is [1]
ie. [undefined,{our object}];

Comment: Suggest using strict equality (`===`) when testing for `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question i can only deduce the following are what you want

1. A particular object shouldn't be in the array more than once.
2. The Length of the array shouldn't be greater than 2, which will
   answer that you maybe only want an object in the array but the first
   element can be undefined tho.

A proper way to do this will be:

```js
let myArray = [undefined, "object", "object"];
//check that myArray only contains "object"
//1: The "object" should not be in the array more than once
//2: I presume you also want the array length not to be greater than 2
console.log(containsObjectOnly("object", myArray));

function containsObjectOnly(obj, myArray) {
  var isOnly = false;
  let xTimes = 0;
  let found = myArray.filter((value) => {
    if (value == obj && xTimes === 0) {
      isOnly = true;
      xTimes++;
    } else if (xTimes > 0 && value == obj) {
      isOnly = false;
    }
    return isOnly;
  });
  return isOnly && !(myArray.length > 2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (myArray.length === 1 && JSON.stringify(myObject) === JSON.stringify(myArray[0])) {
    console.log("myObject is in here, and it's the only element!");
}
else {
    console.log('nope!');
}
```

Comment: what about function objects or objects containing circular references? Comparison of object values is sufficient.